# How to LOCATE photos, on iPhone, which aren't importing to my Mac?

Tags: iphone, photos, import

There are a few old-ish photos (2019 or so) from the previous (family) user of my iPhone which just refuse to import into Photos on my Mac. That's fine; my 17-year-old sister has thousands of photos and does not need these five selfies! So I want to remove them from my iPhone—but I can only do that *on* my iPhone, and I don't know how to locate them there.

I can't double-click on yet-to-be-imported photos to get a full view with details about the image. If I had the date for the photo, I could navigate to that timeframe on my iPhone and remove it there, but I can't figure out how to access that info from my Mac before the photo has been imported!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there *is* a way to access details about an image before it's been imported!

There is no menu item for it, and the Import view disables the photo context menu, but **the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘I</kbd> (Command+`I`) shows the Info panel on selected items in the Import view.** This includes the date the photo was taken:

[image: Info floating panel: IMG_4195.JPG, August 5, 2020 at 5:57:37 PM, and camera details like 'Apple iPhone 8']

From there, you can navigate by date on the iPhone to delete - or manually export (share) - the photos which aren't cooperating with Import.

(If you have a bulky amount of photos which won't come through, you may consider trying Apple's Image Capture app [under "Utilities" or "Other" in the Launchpad], which anecdotally seems more reliable. Image Capture sorts by date, so you can navigate to the right timeframe once you've identified the date through the "secret" Info panel in Photos' Import view.)